# How do I make the output of a cell different keywords depending on if it's a number or not?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

O9 contains either a number or a word.

I have made this formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(O9),IF(O9<=74),"Alpha",IF(O9>=75),"Bravo"),IF(AND(O9<=65,M9="C","Charlie",IF(AND(O9<=65,M9="D","Delta",IF(AND(O9<=65,M9="E","Echo"
```

What I wanted to happen was, if the contents of O9 is a number, the output would be either Alpha (if O9<=74) or Bravo(if O9>=75). If O9's contents are not a number, the output would either be Charlie, Delta, or Echo.

I think I may have misplaced some commas or parentheses and made mistakes on them which made my false value (for the *"IF(ISNUMBER)"* ) unidentifiable.

This is the error message:

> There's a problem with this formula.

If I try editing the parentheses placement, the error message says

> There are too many arguments.

New to Excel so, sorry for the question. Not really aware of other formulas/commands other than the basic ones (sum, average, etc.) Thank you in advance to those who will answer!

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(O9),IF(O9<=74,"Alpha","Bravo"),IF(M9="C","Charlie",IF(M9="D","Delta",IF(M9="E","Echo"))))` maybe? But I don't quite understand your `AND()` to check if `O9` is smaller/greater than 65 when your conclusion was that `O9` does **not** contain a number to begin with?

Comment: At the very least you lack closing parantheses for all your `AND`-statements, in addition it looks like the end of your formula is missing?

Comment: Is your number always an integer?  i.e. can it be 74.5?

Comment: @JvdV O9 could **either** be a number or C,D,E. Sorry for the misunderstanding! Will give your suggestion a try later, thank you very much!

Comment: @Chronocidal Hmm. I have formatted cells to not contain decimal places

Comment: @CT3 formatting cells doesn't change the actual value they store, it only changes how they display it.  Changing a cell's number formatting (e.g. removing decimal places) has no more effect than, say, changing the font colour - it _looks_ different but the value is the same.

Comment: @Chronocidal gotcha. Then my numbers aren't always integers. Some of them actually have decimals

Answer (score 1):

Break it down into 3 steps.  First step "is it a number?"

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(O9), IS_A_NUMBER, NOT_A_NUMBER)
```

Next step, for `IS_A_NUMBER`, "is less-than 75?" (This will ensure that number *between* 74 and 75 give a value — such as 74.1 — and eliminates the need to both <=74 and >=75 as separate conditions)

```
IF(O9<75,"Alpha","Bravo")
```

Put those steps together:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(O9), IF(O9<75,"Alpha","Bravo"), NOT_A_NUMBER)
```

Finally, match "C", "D" and "E" to "Charlie", "Delta" and "Echo" for `NOT_A_NUMBER`:

```
VLOOKUP(O9, {"C", "Charlie"; "D", "Delta"; "E", "Echo"}, 2, False)
```

And put *everything* together:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(O9), IF(O9<75,"Alpha","Bravo"), VLOOKUP(O9, {"C", "Charlie"; "D", "Delta"; "E", "Echo"}, 2, False))
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! I will try doing this later. :)

Comment: Wow, this works! (I actually had a typo in a cell number so I edited it in your formula) and it works!!!! Thank you, you're a huuuuge lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Office365 then you might want to try `=IFS(...)`, in which you enter logical conditions followed by their outputs (as many condition-output pairs as you like) and it gives the output for the first condition that's true.

In this case that would probably be:

```
=IFS(M9="C", "Charlie", M9="D", "Delta", M9="E", "Echo", O9<=74, "Alpha", O9>74, "Bravo", 1=1, "Error")
```

The last two arguments make sure that if none of the previous possibilities are triggered it will say 'Error'.

NB that this won't work on some versions of excel - give it a try and see.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give this a try later and will update you on whether it works or not.

Comment: Hmm, this ends up as a #NAME error. Will look into it more. Thank you!